# 'You have made too many incorrect reviews'- How can I improve?

Tags: support, review-suspension

I got my first review ban.

> Review You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a
>   task you should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11390694.
>
> Come back tomorrow to continue reviewing.

Going to to all my [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54506/jayan?tab=activity&sort=reviews) looks difficult and error prone. Above link only shows one question/answer. I am sure there were more.

How can I get feedback on improvements needed?  Could SO moderator/**automated-tool** send a summary of general improvements along with the ban.

Comment: You don't have to revisit all of your reviews. Maybe the ones from the last couple of days you have been reviewing or so.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508 for a script that can help with this.

Comment: You're not going to see what you did wrong by glaring at your own reviews. Search for "audit" in meta, pick each and everyone that looks like fire is breathing out of it, and read the discussions. The truth is out there.

Comment: Library recommendations should smell of bad questions.  Either skip them or ding 'em.

Comment: @Will: That may be case.  I consider "library recommendations" as good to keep, especially when they are old.  Next time I will skip them

Comment: @Jayan Those types of questions don't belong on the site.  Your reviews should reflect that.

Comment: I won't go as far as saying that that looks like a *questionable* review audit, but it does look like it's at least rather advanced. That looks like it could be an answer to a question, but my guess is that it's verbose spam.